# What is use of each folder in System.Environment.SpecialFolder in iOS Xamarin

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can anyone please explain the structure of the folder structure for all the below mentioned SpecialFolder in Xamarin iOS?

1. Environment.SpecialFolder.AdminTools
2. Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
3. Environment.SpecialFolder.CDBurning
4. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonAdminTools
5. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData
6. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory
7. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments
8. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonMusic
9. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonOemLinks
10. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures
11. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles
12. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFilesX86
13. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPrograms
14. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu
15. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartup
16. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonTemplates
17. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonVideos
18. Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
19. Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory
20. Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts
21. Environment.SpecialFolder.History
22. Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache
23. Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData
24. Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalizedResources
25. Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
26. Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic
27. Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures
28. Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos
29. Environment.SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts
30. Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
31. Environment.SpecialFolder.PrinterShortcuts
32. Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles
33. Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86
34. Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent
35. Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources Environment.SpecialFolder.SendTo
36. Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu
37. Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup Environment.SpecialFolder.System
38. Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86
39. Environment.SpecialFolder.Templates
40. Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile
41. Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows
42. Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears the Xamarin API documentation is missing for this enum.

Here are a few of the values but not all:
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData is $HOME/.config, which is /data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files/.config.

Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData is $HOME/.local/share, which is /data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files/.local/share.

Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal is $HOME, which is /data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files.

[Xamarin Forum Link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3773/system-environment-specialfolder)